# Odoo qweb call python method

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to modify the RFQ report and in that I wanted to call a python method from the Qweb report,

here is some sample code,

```
<span t-field ="o.my_custom_fuction()" />
```

and my python function is like

```
@api.model
def my_custom_function(self):
    return "some_value"
```

But it is giving me error like 
qwebException : "my_custom_function()" while evaluating.

Any clue what I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

> > The t-field directive can only be used when performing field access (a.b) on a "smart" record (result of the browse method).

To call that function You will need to use `t-esc` (takes an expression, evaluates it and prints the content):

```
<span t-esc ="o.my_custom_fuction()" />
```

I used [Odoo QWEB reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html)